# "[object Object]" Why do I get it with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

So I searched through Google and Stackoverflow, but for the life of me, I can't seem to find why I get an "[object Object]" alert box with this code. I simply do not understand why I get that. What part of my code makes that alert occur?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
            <style>

            #circle{
                background-color: green;
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                border-radius: 100px;
            }
            .square{
                background-color: red;
                width:300px;
                height:300px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="circle"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <script>
                $("div").click(function(){
                    alert($(this).css("width","400px"));
                });
            </script>
            </body>
```

Comment: What you want to alert then?

Comment: because every jQuery function return his own instance (= end with "return this" in order to be chained. so your function is doing the same as :alert(this) or this is an object. So you get [object Object]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery `css` method is overloaded.

If you pass it **one** argument, which is the name of a CSS property, then it will return the *value of that property*.

If you pass it **two** arguments, which are the name of the property and a value to set it to, then it will set the property and then return *the jQuery object* (so that you can chain further method calls off it).

When you convert an object to a string, unless `toString` has been overridden, you get `"[object Object]"`.

In a nutshell: **Because you are setting data instead of reading it**.

Comment: I was just about to update this post, because I realized that the alert box was showing up because of the setting of the data, and that removing the alert, or the input, fixed the issue. However, your answer was a very detailed explanation and now I understand better, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you try `console.log($(this).css("width","400px"))`, you'll see it will actually print you... an object, a jQuery object so you can chain methods on it.
If you want to print the width after the width change, you'll have to do this:

```
$("div").click(function(){
    alert($(this).css("width","400px").css("width"));
});
```

This will show "400px".